# Connecting to Oracle DB 11g with 10g client - syntax error

Tags: oracle, instantclient

On a Ubunut machine, I use this command to connect to an Oracle 11g database with the 11g instant client:

```
sqlplus username/password@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = the.address.com)(PORT = theport)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = service.address.com)))
```

Which works fine… On Mac OS X Mountain Lion I could only get the instant client 10g (32bit version) running, which gives me this error when I try to connect using the same line:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Did the syntax changed from 10g to 11g?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put quotes around the connect string, parenthesis can be interpreted by your shell otherwise.

Something like:

```
sqlplus user/pass@"(DESCRIPTION...)"
```

Comment: Oh man thanks ; ) Still confusing, I use BASH on both machines and it works on Ubuntu without parenthesis.

Comment: You've probably got one space "luckily misplaced" somewhere. You should not count on this working anywhere without quotes.

Comment: I thought it too, but the line works fine without quotes on Ubuntu – I copy&pasted it. However, I'll use quotes in future ; )